# How do I transition an entity to an enum in JPA?

Tags: jpa, kotlin, enums

I have an entity in JPA that an I am interested in transitioning into an enum.

The problem I am facing is that I have a relationship into this table that is mapped by a join table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
data class User(
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_certificates",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "certificate_id")]
    )
    var certificates: List<Certficate> = listOf()
)
```

And here is the enum I am interested in transitioning to,

```
enum class Certificate(val id: Int) {
  FOO(1),
  BAR(2),
  BAZ(3)
}
```

Is it possible to transition this into an enum that has an id and use the same `user_certificates` table to store the enums attached to the entity with the existing relationship?

Answer (score 2):

The same table can be used with the following mapping in the user entity class:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetClass = Certificate::class)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_certificates", joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id")])
@Column(name = "certificate_id")
@Convert(converter = CertificateEnumConverter::class)
var certificates: List<Certificate> = listOf(),
```

The converter looks like,

```
class CertificateEnumConverter : AttributeConverter<Certificate, Int> {
  override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(attribute: Certificate?) = attribute!!.id

  override fun convertToEntityAttribute(dbData: Int?) = Certificate.fromId(dbData!!)
}
```

Comment: Would be nice to see this with the double exclamation mark assumptions resolved.